# How do I print the average time taken to open a file for reading?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and I have to do some automation at my work. I have to take a path to a directory containing multiple files and print the average time taken to read or open a particular file. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You should post your code and ask questions about specific problems you have.

Comment: I basically know how to open and read files. I need some help with reading time stamps

Comment: @brett: a file's timestamp is very different than "the time taken to read or open a file".  What do you really want to accomplish?

Comment: I need to read files in a directory 64kb each time and I want to print avg time taken to open and read files.

Comment: @daxim: I think your title edit makes it more about open than reading than it necessarily is.

Comment: @brett: what do you mean by "64kb each time"?   I can think of three or four ways to interpret that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl has fabulous benchmarking and timing tools.

While [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/Time-HiRes-1.9721/HiRes.pm) can time accurately, you may wish to consider more complete benchmarking tools to see if the opening, reading or something else reading is the bottleneck. You will also need to write the code to time the relevant bits if Time::HiRes is the only tool in your bag.

For statement level benchmarking, I use [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.04/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm). It is fairly simple to use, and has a beautiful HTML output that will show what is going on under the hood of your program.

For very fast, simple subroutine level benchmarking I use the core module [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html). Randal Schwartz has an article about using Benchmark in the Unix Review [here](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col49.html). Benchmark can be used to time a statement or subroutine literally in seconds. It is best combined with Time::HiRes for more accurate timing. Benchmark is a core distribution; Time::HiRes needs to be installed from CPAN.

The easiest from the get-go is to install Time::HiRes and then use Benchmark for a simple table on the time of the relevant statements or subroutines. If there seems to be more to dig into, use the more complex Devel::NYTProf.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Time::HiRes) to be able to time things more precisely.

Why is it that you want to print an average time?  That's going to be really hard to do in any meaningful way; caching is going to make reads after the first much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use time() function to get the time at start and end of the file open
Then you can calculate the difference between them. Then you can average out. You can do the same with reading files too

Comment: time() won't work well, particularly for operations that are better measured in milliseconds.

Comment: Use Time::HiRes. time() has only integer second accuracy.